# Find $\partial \sum_{i=1}^K a_i \log f_i / \partial f_l $ when $\sum f_i =1$ and $f(x) \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

Sorry if this question is too easy. But I need to find 
$$
\dfrac{\partial \sum_{i=1}^K a_i \log f_i}{\partial f_l }
$$ where $\sum f_i =1$ and $f(x) \in [0,1]$. Each $f_i$ is a just smooth enough function on for example real spaces $f_i: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ ($i=1,\dots,K$). (We can relax them more if required.)

It's quite confusing to me because we can write $f_i$ as
$$
f_i(x) = 1 - \sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^K f_j(x).
$$
Because of this, all I can calculate is
$$
\sum_{i \neq j}\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial f_j} = -1
$$

Especially, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.02906.pdf) claims
$$
\dfrac{a_i}{f_i} = \dfrac{a_l}{f_l}
$$ for all $l \neq i$ 
when
$$
\dfrac{\partial \sum_{i=1}^K a_i \log f_i}{\partial f_i } =0.
$$
How can we derive it?

Comment: Isn't $$\frac{\partial}{\partial f_j} \log f_i= \frac{f_{i, j}}{f_i}?$$

Comment: If you mean $\partial f_i / \partial f_j$ by $f_{i,j} $, yes.